# How to use photoshop or illustrator or CSS to draw this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, css

In Powerpoint, it's easy to create this effect. [Gradient fill] -> [Rectangular] 
[image]

If it is possible, can CSS do this? If not, I was wondering how I can do this in photoshop or illustrator with only a few steps?

The reason I need to do this is that I can't move the light beam to the middle top of the shape in powerpoint. It can only be on top right corner so I have to choose different softwares.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a forum where you'll find tutorials on the very basic functions of design applications. See our FAQ in the help section of the site for the kinds of questions that are suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Gradient Tool** in either Photoshop or Illustrator to create a gradient. For that particular gradient, a **Gradient Mesh in Illustrator** may be better, provided you know Illustrator.

---

This is a *very basic* software usage question. (I hesitate to even say it's on topic) Reviewing the help files or using Google to find basic tutorials will assist you faster than posting questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Learn PS basics tool like gradient. You can achieve it by using gradient

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `css` to do this or something close. Go to [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) and check below the heading "Using Angles".